# Retrieve a cookie to set a Background Image

Tags: javascript, image, cookies

I a bit of noob and a magpie when it comes to using code in any web project I have tried.
I'm still new to the game here.

Currently I'm building an Information Panel for my office network that will sit on the Active Desktop (We are still tied in to IE8 here so there's nothing modern about anything I can use!)

What I'd like is the ability for the user to have the Info Panel full screen on their desktop and then set the background of the  tag to a desired image.

Currently I have (in a very raw form)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setBackgroundImage()
{
    var url = document.getElementById('bgchanger').value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
    setCookie('userbg', url, 30);
}

</script>

<body onload="setBackgroundImage()" id="bg">

<input type="file" value ="Look" name="myFileSelect" input type="text" id="bgchanger" placeholder="Change Background Add URL" />
<input type="button" onclick="setBackgroundImage();" value="Change!" />
```

Which enables a user image selection plus setting of a cookie.

The bit I don't know is how to retrieve it and set it.

Clearly there has to be some logical stuff in there to check for a cookie, set the value as the background and not use the inputted text if one exists.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: One thing of a few to fix... you're going to need to put your inputs within the body tag. Ex: `<body onload="setBackgroundImage()" id="bg"><!-- INPUTS GO HERE --></body>`

Comment: Sure :-) I realise that - like I said, it was a just a raw start. That wouldn't preclude any code form working though? My cookie is being stored with my file name, I'm just not javascript savvy enough to be able to code a retrieval statement and use it as the URL.

Comment: Do you want the user to link to an image or upload an image? Linking would be a lot easier as you wouldn't need to upload it to a server

Comment: @ChrisSandiford ok, I was just confused because the body was below the inputs originally. Sometimes people on SO don't even know things like that.

Comment: @dhsto No probs. It was just a gash file I was playing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/cJy63/4/) with the code. The cookies get deleted if you refresh the page, but clicking run multiple times is fine.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="image-form">
  <label for="url">Image URL</label>
  <input type="text" id="url" value="http://stylegerms.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Techno-Desktop-backgrounds-Desktop-Wallpaper.jpg" />
  <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="updateURL()" />
</div>
<!-- Place the JavaScript before </body> -->
```

Here's the JavaScript you need

```
window.onload = function() {
  setBackground();
}

function updateURL() {
  var newURL = document.getElementById('url').value;
  setCookie('URL', newURL, 365);
  document.body.style.background = 'url('+newURL+') no-repeat';
  document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
  document.body.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = newURL;
  document.body.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").sizingMethod = 'scale';
}

function setBackground() {
  var URL = getCookie('URL');
  document.body.style.background = 'url('+URL+') no-repeat';
  document.body.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
  document.body.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = URL;
  document.body.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").sizingMethod = 'scale';
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
  var exdate=new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
  var c_value = document.cookie;
  var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");

  if (c_start == -1)
    c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");

  if (c_start == -1) {
    c_value = null;
  } else {
    c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
    var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);

    if (c_end == -1)
      c_end = c_value.length;

    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
  return c_value;
}
```

And here's a bit of CSS

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    -ms-filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7", sizingMethod="scale")';
}

#image-form {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, great work - it works a treat. I had a lot of that code from W3schools but couldn't organise it properly. I added my original search button back in so now it's exactly what I need. I start my javascript course next week. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChrisSandiford No problem! Good Luck on your course! If my answer answered your question, don't forget to accept and up vote it. Thanks

Comment: I need a 15 rep to vote it up apparently Graham. One further thing

Comment: One further thing, I would like to scale the images selected to the window. I have successfully implemented the <IE8 sizing workaround, **filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="..images/overlay.png", sizingMethod="scale");** in CSS but can't apply it to the js

Comment: @ChrisSandiford are you using a default image? ps you can wrap code in ``` marks (one on each side).

Comment: I realised about the code markup afterwards - thanks! Unfortunately that IE hack references a default image but clearly I will be using the one that has been set by the user via the `<input>` button and subsequent cookies. SO I somehow need to get the `document.body.style.background = 'url('+URL+')';` part into that AplphaImageLoader line.

Comment: Can you give [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/cJy63/2/) a try? Basically you have to set the filter in css and then update the value in javascript. I set the default image to a transparent 1x1 pixel. Unfortunately I don't have IE8 to test on.

Comment: Hi Graham, I see what you're trying to do there but I get a script error though around the `document.body.filters` line when applying it at my end.

Comment: @ChrisSandiford I've updated my answer with new code and a new jsfiddle. I've tested the answer on IE8 so all should work well. I realised I was updating the `src` but forgetting that `sizingMethod` gets reset after the `src` changes. You will see the following error in the console of none IE browsers, because there is no such thing as `filter`, but it's fine to ignore it. Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'item' of undefined `

Comment: Hi @Graham Walters, sorry about this - the code still falls over at the `document.body.filters` line in my html each time (when used as a background desktop file), yet in an IE 8 browser window I get no erors.. But it still doesn't work - the background remains the same size as the input image, either too big or small. However, it is working perfectly in Chrome with no errors..:-S

Comment: @ChrisSandiford it works in chrome because chrome supports `background-size: cover;`. I've tested the code in IE8 and it works for me so must be something else on your page. Try clearing your cache. If the problem persists, I recommend you open a new question about `AlphaImageLoader` not scaling.

Comment: OK Graham thanks. I copied your code from jsfiddle into a clean html file and I still get a script error. I'll pursue it. Many thanks for all your help, you have given me some good advice!